# Beginners Calculus and derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I new to Calculus and am trying to understand how the various rules have been applied to the following questions, in order to arrive at the answers. I am familiar with the power, sum, product rules etc, but can't fully understand how they have been applied here. Thank you in advance.

In the following equations, $a$ and $b$ are constants, and $E$ is a function of the variable $t$. Find expressions for ݀$d\frac{dx}{dt}$ in terms of $a,b,E$ and $\dfrac{dE}{dt}$.

$x = aE + b$

Answer: $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = aE \dfrac{dE}{dt}$

$x = a \exp (-bE)$

Answer: $\dfrac{dx/dt} = -ab \exp (-bE) \dfrac{dE}{dt}$

Comment: This feels like an odd practice question for someone new to calculus since the notation doesn't distinguish between functions and constants. Can you tell us where this question came from?

Answer (score 2):

The first answer is incorrect. If $x(t)=aE(t)+b$ then

$\displaystyle \frac {dx}{dt} = a \frac {dE}{dt}$ not $\displaystyle aE \frac {dE}{dt}$.

For the second questions, use the chain rule:

$\displaystyle x(t) = a e^{-bE(t)} = af(E(t))$

where $f(E) = e^{-bE}$. So

$\displaystyle \frac {dx}{dt} = a \frac {df}{dE} \frac {dE} {dt} =  a(-be^{-bE}) \frac {dE}{dt} = -\left(abe^{-bE} \right) \frac {dE}{dt} $

Comment: Thanks for the replies. This clears things up, as I couldn’t get my head around the first answer, because it was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The first appears to be wrong.  Should be $\DeclareMathOperator{\d}{d}\d x/\d t=a\d E/\d t$

The second is right, because $\exp$ is its own derivative.